# Django Rest Framework Serialization fails: 'MetaDict' object has no attribute 'pk'

Tags: mongodb, mongoengine, django-rest-framework

I am using the Django Rest Framework with a MongoDB and I am trying to retrieve a document from the MongoDB and then serialize it to json in order to send it back in response to a request.

I have a database model that looks like this:

```
class TTest(Document):
    user_id = StringField()
    submission_status = StringField()
```

and the corresponding serializer:

```
class TTestSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = models.TTest
        pk = "_id"
```

Now having these, I wish to retrieve a document from the DB and I tried to follow exactly the tutorial regarding serialization using Django Rest Framework:

```
queryset = models.TTest.objects.filter(user_id='bbb')   # retrieving documents using mongoengine
serializer = TTestSerializer(queryset)
dt = serializer.data
print "DATA SERIALIZED: ", dt
```

When I am running these lines, trying to serialize, I get back this error:

```
AttributeError: 'MetaDict' object has no attribute 'pk'
```

Theoretically I think it should work, since I declared in the serializer's metadata that the primary key is "_id"...Can anyone help  me with an advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

There's no such option 'pk' in Serializer classes, so that won't have any affect.

I don't know much about mongoengine, but I expect you need to be using plain 'Serializer' classes rather than 'ModelSerializer' if the object isn't a standard Django model instance.

It'd be worth asking questions about REST framework and mongoengine on the REST framework mailing list, since I know there's some other folks who've been doing the same.

https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!forum/django-rest-framework

Answer (score 0):

Mongoengine is not a direct replacement of Django's ORM and as such may not natively integrate with libraries expecting the normal ORM.

You might want to try http://django-tastypie-mongoengine.readthedocs.org/en/latest/ that has been made to work with mongoengine.

Comment: Please note that django-tastypie-mongoengine is licensed under AGPLv3